# How can I use a hyperlink to display external page inside a div on my page?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a page with a menu on the left (with hyperlinks to external pages). I have a div on the right, called "main-area". When I click on the menu links, I would like the external page to open in my "main-area" div. How can I do that?

Comment: If you paste the relevant lines of code from your project, including any Javascript that your HTML elements might reference, you can get specific help. In general, you'll need to make it so that the <a> tags don't open new windows with that page, but instead change the `src` attribute of an `iframe` element. [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The target should be a iframe, not a div.

```
<a href="URL" target="main-area">URL</a>

<iframe name="main-area"></iframe>
```